# How to use Oracle SQL to create a calendar

Tags: sql, oracle

I can create the calendar using this script:
[image]

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (NEW_YWEEK = MIN(NEW_YWEEK)
               OVER(PARTITION BY MON ORDER BY NEW_YWEEK)) THEN
          MON_NAME
         ELSE
          MON_NAME
       END AS MONTH,
     --  NEW_YWEEK AS YWEEK,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MON ORDER BY NEW_YWEEK) AS MWEEK,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '1', MDAY, NULL)) AS SUN,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '2', MDAY, NULL)) AS MON,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '3', MDAY, NULL)) AS TUE,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '4', MDAY, NULL)) AS WED,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '5', MDAY, NULL)) AS THU,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '6', MDAY, NULL)) AS FRI,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '7', MDAY, NULL)) AS SAT
  FROM (SELECT DAYOFYEAR AS EVERYDAY,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'mm') AS MON,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'Month') AS MON_NAME,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'w') AS MWEEK,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww') AS YWEEK,
               CASE
                 WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd'), 'd') > '1') AND
                      (TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') <
                      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd'), 'd')) THEN
                  TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww') + 1, 'fm00')
                 ELSE
                  TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww')
               END AS NEW_YWEEK,
              TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') AS WDAY,
                             /*decode(
TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') ,
'2','1','3','2','4','3','5','4' ,'6','5','7','6' ,'7' )AS WDAY,*/
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'dd') AS MDAY
          FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd') + LEVEL -1 AS DAYOFYEAR
                  FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '1231', 'yyyymmdd'),
                                   'ddd')))
 GROUP BY MON, MON_NAME, NEW_YWEEK;
```

But the above is take sunday as first day of a week, I want to take monday as first day of week as below, how to make it, thanks!

[image]

Comment: By the way i believe it's just a simple as removing `SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '1', MDAY, NULL)) AS SUN,` to come as last..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this much more simply by doing:

```
WITH dts AS (SELECT TRUNC(to_date('&year', 'yyyy'), 'yyyy') + LEVEL -1 AS dt
             FROM   dual
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_char(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '1231', 'yyyymmdd'), 'ddd')),
    dts2 AS (SELECT dt,
                    TRUNC(dt, 'mm') dt_mon,
                    TRUNC(dt, 'iw') dt_start_of_week,
                    to_char(dt, 'fmdd') day_of_month
             FROM   dts)
SELECT to_char(dt_mon, 'fmMonth') "MONTH",
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY to_char(dt_mon, 'fmMonth') ORDER BY dt_start_of_week) week_num,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dt = dt_start_of_week THEN day_of_month END) mon,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dt = dt_start_of_week + 1 THEN day_of_month END) tue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dt = dt_start_of_week + 2 THEN day_of_month END) wed,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dt = dt_start_of_week + 3 THEN day_of_month END) thu,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dt = dt_start_of_week + 4 THEN day_of_month END) fri,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dt = dt_start_of_week + 5 THEN day_of_month END) sat,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dt = dt_start_of_week + 6 THEN day_of_month END) sun
FROM   dts2
GROUP BY dt_mon,
         to_char(dt_mon, 'fmMonth'),
         dt_start_of_week
ORDER BY dt_mon, dt_start_of_week;
```

If you want the week to start with a Sunday, you can change the dt_start_of_week column to be `trunc(dt + 1, 'iw') - 1 dt_start_of_week` in the dts2 subquery, as well as changing the aliases of the columns from mon-sun to sun-sat.

This works by finding the iso week start day, which is always a Monday. Then you can use that, to group by, plus throw a row_number analytic function over it to find the week of the month number of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Value of `TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd')`  depends on value of NLS_TERRITORY parameter.

You have 2 options:

**Option 1**
Set NLS_TERRITORY parameter to the value in which Monday is treated as 1st day (for example 'UNITED KINGDOM') and execute below query (`SUM(DECODE(WDAY,` has been adjusted):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'UNITED KINGDOM';

SELECT CASE
         WHEN (NEW_YWEEK = MIN(NEW_YWEEK)
               OVER(PARTITION BY MON ORDER BY NEW_YWEEK)) THEN
          MON_NAME
         ELSE
          MON_NAME
       END AS MONTH,
     --  NEW_YWEEK AS YWEEK,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MON ORDER BY NEW_YWEEK) AS MWEEK,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '1', MDAY, NULL)) AS MON,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '2', MDAY, NULL)) AS TUE,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '3', MDAY, NULL)) AS WED,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '4', MDAY, NULL)) AS THU,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '5', MDAY, NULL)) AS FRI,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '6', MDAY, NULL)) AS SAT,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '7', MDAY, NULL)) AS SUN
  FROM (SELECT DAYOFYEAR AS EVERYDAY,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'mm') AS MON,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'Month') AS MON_NAME,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'w') AS MWEEK,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww') AS YWEEK,
               CASE
                 WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd'), 'd') > '1') AND
                      (TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') <
                      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd'), 'd')) THEN
                  TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww') + 1, 'fm00')
                 ELSE
                  TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww')
               END AS NEW_YWEEK,
              TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') AS WDAY,
                             /*decode(
TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') ,
'2','1','3','2','4','3','5','4' ,'6','5','7','6' ,'7' )AS WDAY,*/
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'dd') AS MDAY
          FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd') + LEVEL -1 AS DAYOFYEAR
                  FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '1231', 'yyyymmdd'),
                                   'ddd'))
--where TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'Month') = 'November'
                                   )
 GROUP BY MON, MON_NAME, NEW_YWEEK;
```

**Option 2**
Don't touch NLS_TERRITORY parameter and execute below query (`SUM(DECODE(WDAY,` has been adjusted and the way how value of `WDAY` is calculated has been changed):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (NEW_YWEEK = MIN(NEW_YWEEK)
               OVER(PARTITION BY MON ORDER BY NEW_YWEEK)) THEN
          MON_NAME
         ELSE
          MON_NAME
       END AS MONTH,
     --  NEW_YWEEK AS YWEEK,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MON ORDER BY NEW_YWEEK) AS MWEEK,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '1', MDAY, NULL)) AS MON,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '2', MDAY, NULL)) AS TUE,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '3', MDAY, NULL)) AS WED,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '4', MDAY, NULL)) AS THU,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '5', MDAY, NULL)) AS FRI,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '6', MDAY, NULL)) AS SAT,
       SUM(DECODE(WDAY, '7', MDAY, NULL)) AS SUN
  FROM (SELECT DAYOFYEAR AS EVERYDAY,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'mm') AS MON,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'Month') AS MON_NAME,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'w') AS MWEEK,
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww') AS YWEEK,
               CASE
                 WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd'), 'd') > '1') AND
                      (TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') <
                      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd'), 'd')) THEN
                  TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww') + 1, 'fm00')
                 ELSE
                  TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'ww')
               END AS NEW_YWEEK,
               DECODE(MOD(TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd')-1, 7), 0,7, TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd')-1) AS WDAY,
                             /*decode(
TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'd') ,
'2','1','3','2','4','3','5','4' ,'6','5','7','6' ,'7' )AS WDAY,*/
               TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'dd') AS MDAY
          FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(&YEAR || '0101', 'yyyymmdd') + LEVEL -1 AS DAYOFYEAR
                  FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&YEAR || '1231', 'yyyymmdd'),
                                   'ddd'))
--where TO_CHAR(DAYOFYEAR, 'Month') = 'November'
                                   )
 GROUP BY MON, MON_NAME, NEW_YWEEK;
```